# Stacking multiple plots in R (Raster + elevation line)

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, raster

basically I am trying to plot two graphs in the same graph, and I want that both scales (in x) are identical. First graph is a raster, second one is the elevation of each cell when the raster is cut by an horizontal line.

So far this is the code I have written.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

T1_Domain <- raster("C:/Users/rm053078/Desktop/test1DEM.asc")
T1_Section <- readOGR("C:/Users/rm053078/Desktop/Section.shp")
T1_lat_profile <- extract(T1_Domain, T1_Section)


par(mfrow=c(2,1), xaxs = "i")

plot(T1_Domain,
     ylab = "y",
     xlab = "x",
     xlim = c(T1_Domain@extent@xmin,T1_Domain@extent@xmax))

points(400,50, pch = 4)
text(400,50,labels = "1", pos = 4)
points(600,50, pch = 4)
text(600,50,labels = "1", pos = 4)

plot(x=seq(from = T1_Domain@extent@xmin, to = T1_Domain@extent@xmax, length.out = length(T1_lat_profile[[1]])),
     y=T1_lat_profile[[1]],
     type = "l",
     xlab = "x",
     ylab = "z",
     xlim = c(T1_Domain@extent@xmin,T1_Domain@extent@xmax))
```

Although when the code is executed, it seems that I achieved what I want.
[Image when executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s75q.png).

My problem is when I run this as rmarkdown chunk, the graph I got is different [Image when executed in rmarkdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhxzk.png).

Any idea how to achieve this?